# Cosa significa "E picchia delle volate di sotto"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nella versione in italiano del monologo *Il primo miracolo di Gesú Bambino* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> In quell'istante nel cielo stracolmo di stelle è apparso l'arcangelo con un cerchione tremendo piantato sulla testa... e con delle alettone piumate che le andava sbattendo a ventaglio dando schiaffoni alle nuvole e nello svolazzare l’aria gonfiava i panneggi del suo vestito come vele in tempesta! Tutto di traverso lo abbracciava una fascia, 
>   chiara e grande, con su scritto: «ANGELO»... per quelli che non capiscono!
>   
>  
>          Va volteggiando per il cielo gridando: – Uomini di buona volontà, venite! Venite! È nato il Redentore! – E **picchia** delle volate di sotto.

Non capisco del tutto bene il senso di questo "picchia" nell'ultima frase. Infatti, il testo poi parla anche delle "picchiate" dell'angelo. Ho pensato che si riferisse a [questo significato del verbo "picchiare"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/picchiare2/), ma poi ho pensato che non poteva essere perché, in questa accezione, il verbo "picchiare" è transitivo. Qualcuno di voi me lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: Secondo me vuol dire che scende in picchiata di sotto, e l'accezione giusta è quella che hai trovato su Treccani per picchiata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

È proprio il significato riportato da te nell'articolo della Treccani, ovvero si riferisce alla "picchiata" aeronautica.

Può capitare in italiano che alcuni verbi intransitivi si trasformino in transitivi; come riportato in questo [articolo](http://www.linkiesta.it/it/blog-post/2012/08/16/verbi-transitivi-e-intransitivi-una-distinzione-non-sempre-assoluta/9611/) capita spesso quando il complemento oggetto è *"...un nome che presenta la stessa radice del verbo o che è strettamente legato ad esso dal punto di vista semantico"*

Un esempio è *"vivere la vita"*, ed è anche il caso di *"picchiare la volata"* (legame semantico), che può essere a mio parere considerata una sorta di "licenza poetica" dell'autore che serve a rendere l'immagine più incisiva.

Da notare infine ci sono anche altre eccezioni, a me piace ricordare la frase *"correre un rischio"* ;)

Comment: Se il complemento presenta la stessa radice del verbo, si parla di complemento dell’oggetto interno.