# Qual è il significato di "incarcato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nella versione in italiano del monologo *Il primo miracolo di Gesú Bambino* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> BRUAAMMM! (*Mima una picchiata dell’angelo che si getta per poi sfrecciare radente il 
>   suolo*) Con i pastori che gli urlano: – Oh, disgraziato, ci fai andar via il latte alle pecore!
>   (*Mima un’altra picchiata dell’angelo che per poco non li travolge. A gran voce*) – È nato il Redentoreee... BRUAMMM! 
>         (*Accenna una reazione infuriata dei pastori*) – Che te ne andassi a sbatter contro alla 
>   montagna!, col cerchione **incarcato** fino al mento! Tutte le piume spantegate [disperse]! Gallinaccio!

Nel [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/incarcato) ho trovato che "incarcato" è una forma obsoleta e letteraria per "incaricato". Tuttavia, a me non sembra che questo termine abbia molto senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "incarcato" in questo brano?

Per si può essere utile, per la versione originale di questo monologo, Fo spiega nel prologo a questa storia che appare nel libro *Mistero buffo*, pubblicato da Einaudi:
«Nel rappresentarvi questa storia, uso un linguaggio che è l'insieme di parecchi dialetti del Nord, tra i quali prevale il veneto». Il termine che appare in questa versione è "incarcào".

Comment: A me ricorda vagamente il termine veneto *incalcato* (incastrato), ma non so se sia giusto. Tieni conto che Fo nel grammelot prende a prestito numerosi termini da lingue regionali di tutta Europa, particolarmente Italia, Francia e Spagna.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Infatti, per la versione originale di questo monologo, Fo spiega: «Nel rappresentarvi questa storia, uso un linguaggio che è l'insieme di parecchi dialetti del Nord, tra i quali prevale il veneto». Il termine che appare in questa versione è "incarcào".

Comment: A me ricorda il termine incarcagnato che però mi sembra appartenente al dialetto romano...

Comment: @Charo Il termine veneto (almeno dalle mie parti) è più correttamente *incalcá* (il veneto tende a far cadere l'ultima sillaba rispetto all'italiano). *Incarcao* potrebbe essere qualche variante simile (magari verso il triestino?)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Tuttavia, tenendo conto della precisazione sul linguaggio del proprio Fo, penso che il significato sia sicuramente quello che tu hai accennato. Se vuoi, puoi scriverlo come risposta.

Comment: @Charo Fatto. Se puoi aggiungere alla mia risposta una fonte per la citazione di Fo sarebbe perfetto.

Comment: @L'ho tratta del libro in cui sto leggendo questa storia: *Mistero buffo*, pubblicato da Einaudi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenendo conto che Fo ha dichiarato

> Nel rappresentarvi questa storia, uso un linguaggio che è l'insieme di parecchi dialetti del Nord, tra i quali prevale il veneto.

sospetto che il termine sia di significato simile al veneto *incalcà[to]*, che significa *incastrato*. Vale a dire i pastori stanno augurando all'angelo di fare un incidente in cui il cerchione [l'aureola?] gli finisca incastrato su per il mento.

Comment: Si tratta effettivamente di un cerchione che fa di aureola. Se ne parla nel brano che ho citato in [quest'altra domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8971/707). Per quanto riguarda la citazione di Fo, l'ho inclusa nel testo della domanda.